# The id in different layout xml must be different?

Tags: android

I have two layout xml files, In Main.xml, there is a button named   android:id="@+id/btnClose", and in About.xml there is also a button named   android:id="@+id/btnClose",
Is it Ok?  Thanks!

**Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="3dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
    android:background="#DCDCDC" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/exit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**About.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="3dip"
    android:paddingLeft="7dip"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:text="@string/myreturn" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes it shall work fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be same.

But to avoid confusion/ambiguity it is better to have different ids as suggested by blackbelt.

You can `findViewById`  of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.  So if you have same ids in different xml layout it's fine.

If you have the below

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose); // initialize button
```

You can findViewById of the current view hierarchy. In your case main.xml

If you have the below

```
setContentView(R.layout.about);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose); // initialize button
```

Both the above cases are valid coz both `main.xml` and `about.xml` have button with id `@+id/btncClose`

Suppose you have second button  with id `@+id/button2` in `about.xml` and you have the below

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

You will get `NullPointerException` because your current view hierarchy set to the activity is of `main.xml` not `about.xml`. `main.xml` does not have a button with id `button2`.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not mandatory. `findViewById()` refers to the current `views hierarchy. Imo it is preferred to avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is fine since both id's are in different xml. But you yourself will get confused at some point if you use these id's regularly in the coding. So it is good to have different ids eg `@+id/btnCloseMain` and `@+id/btnCloseAbout`.